# read CSV file in Cplex

Tags: csv, cplex, opl

my question is related to my previous question. I should make some change in my code. I have a number of nodes between 1 to 100 in the CSV file. I create another CSV file and generate 20 random numbers between the 100 nodes and called them demand points. Each of this demand point has specific demands which are the randomly generate numbers between 1 to 10. I want to read this demand points(the indexes) and their weights. this is the first part of my question? how can I read this?
After that, I need to have a distance between each of these demand points and all nodes. I don't how can I just read the indexes of demand points and calculate the distance between them and all the nodes.
Based on the code that I provided, I need the indexes of demand points for a lot of places. My main problem is that I don't know how should I get these indexes in Cplex through the CSV file.
The demand points with their demands picture is:
 [first column is demandpointindex and second column in their demands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2bph.png)
[this file has 200 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52d8C.jpg)

I tried this code for reading the demand points:

```
tuple demands
    {
    int demandpoint;
    int weight;
    }

    {demands} demand={};

    execute
    {
    var f=new IloOplInputFile("weight.csv");
    while (!f.eof)
    {
    var data = f.readline().split(",");
    if (ar.length==2) 
    demand.add(Opl.intValue(ar[0]),Opl.intValue(ar[1]));
    }
    f.close();
    }
    execute
    {
    writeln(demand);
    }
```

but it's not true.

```
int n=100;
 int p=5;


    tuple demands
    {
    int demandpointindex;
    int weight;
    }

    {demands} demand={};

    execute
    {
    var f=new IloOplInputFile("weight.csv");
    while (!f.eof)
    {
    var data = f.readline().split(",");
    if (ar.length==2) 
    demand.add(Opl.intValue(ar[0]),Opl.intValue(ar[1]));
    }
    f.close();
    }
    execute
    {
    writeln(demand);
    }

 float d[demandpointindexes][facilities];

 execute {
   var f = new IloOplInputFile("test1.csv");
   while (!f.eof) {
      var data = f.readline().split(",");
      if (data.length == 3) 
         d[Opl.intValue(data[0])][Opl.intValue(data[1])] = Opl.floatValue(data[2]);
   }
   writeln(d);
   }

 dvar boolean x[demandpointindexe][facilities];
```

...

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what exactly the problem is here? It seems you have code to read CSV files and as far as I can tell, that code should work. Maybe that CSV is in a different format than you expect? Can you show that CSV file, the expected results and the results that you actually get?

Comment: I have a file which contains 20 number of demand points, their indexes, and their weights. I have another file which has 100 number of nodes and their distances between them. The demand points are chosen from the 100 nodes. I don't know how can I have a distance matrix between the demand points and all the nodes. I should get the indexes of demand points to find them in the nodes and get the distance but I don't know how?

Comment: int index[demandpoints];
 execute {
   var f = new IloOplInputFile("weight.csv");
   while (!f.eof) {
      var data = f.readline().split(",");
      if (data.length == 3) 
         index[Opl.intValue(data[0])] = Opl.intValue(data[1]);
   }
   writeln(index);
   }
   
    float d[demandpoints][facilities];
 
 execute {
   var f = new IloOplInputFile("test1.csv");
   while (!f.eof) {
      var data = f.readline().split(",");
      if (data.length == 3) 
         d[demandpoints][Opl.intValue(data[1])] = Opl.floatValue(data[2]);
   }
   writeln(d);
   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I got your explanation right. Assume you have a file `weight.csv` like this:

```
1,2,
3,7,
4,9,
```

Here the first item in each row is the index of a demand point, the second item is its weight. Then you can parse this as before using this scripting block:

```
tuple demandpoint {
    int index;
    int weight;
}

{demandpoint} demand={};

execute {
  var f = new IloOplInputFile("weight.csv");
  while (!f.eof) {
   var data = f.readline().split(",");
   if (data.length == 3)
     demand.add(Opl.intValue(data[0]), Opl.intValue(data[1]));
  }
  writeln(demand);
}
```

Next you can create a set that contains the indeces of all the demand points:

```
{int} demandpoints = { d.index | d in demand };
```

Assume file test1.csv looks like this

```
1,1,0,
1,2,5,
1,3,6,
1,4,7,
3,1,1,
3,2,1.5,
3,3,0,
3,4,3.5,
4,1,1,
4,2,1.5,
4,3,1.7,
4,4,0,
```

Here the first item is a demand point index, the second item is a facility index and the third item is the distance between first and second item. Note that there are no lines that start with 2 since there is no demand point with index 2 in `weight.csv`. Also note that I assume only 4 facilities here (to keep the file short). You can read the distance between demand points and facitilies as follows:

```
range facilities = 1..4;
float d[demandpoints][facilities];

execute {
  var f = new IloOplInputFile("test1.csv");
  while (!f.eof) {
    var data = f.readline().split(",");
    if (data.length == 4)
      d[Opl.intValue(data[0])][Opl.intValue(data[1])] = Opl.floatValue(data[2]);
  }
  writeln(d);
}
```

The full script (including a dummy objective and constraints so that it can be run) looks:

```
tuple demandpoint {
    int index;
    int weight;
}

{demandpoint} demand={};

execute {
  var f = new IloOplInputFile("weight.csv");
  while (!f.eof) {
   var data = f.readline().split(",");
   if (data.length == 3)
     demand.add(Opl.intValue(data[0]), Opl.intValue(data[1]));
  }
  writeln(demand);
}

// Create a set that contains all the indeces of demand points
// as read from weight.csv
{int} demandpoints = { d.index | d in demand };

range facilities = 1..4;
float d[demandpoints][facilities];

execute {
  var f = new IloOplInputFile("test1.csv");
  while (!f.eof) {
    var data = f.readline().split(",");
    if (data.length == 4)
      d[Opl.intValue(data[0])][Opl.intValue(data[1])] = Opl.floatValue(data[2]);
  }
  writeln(d);
}

minimize 0;
subject to {}
```

It prints

```
 {<1 2> <3 7> <4 9>}
 [[0 5 6 7]
  [1 1.5 0 3.5]
  [1 1.5 1.7 0]]
```

Be careful about how many commas you have in your csv! The code posted above assumes that each line ends with a comma. That is, each line has as many commas as it has fields. If the last field is not terminated by a comma then you have to adapt the parser.

If you have in `test1.csv` the distance between *all* the nodes then it makes sense to first read the data into an array `float distance[facilities][facilities];` and then define the array `d` based on that as

```
float d[i in demandpoints][j in facilities] = distance[i][j];
```

**Update** for the more detailed specification you gave in the comments:
In order to handle the `test1.csv` you explained in the comments you could define a new tuple:

```
tuple Distance {
   int demandpoint;
   int facility;
   float distance;
}
{Distance} distances = {};
```

and read/parse this exactly as you did parse the `weight.csv` file (with one additional field, of course).
Then you can create the distance matrix like so:

```
float d[i in I][j in J] = sum (dist in distances : dist.demandpoint == i && dist.facility == j) dist.distance;
```

Here `I` and `J` are the sets or ranges of demand points and facilities, respectively. See above for how you can get a set of all demand points defined in the tuple set. The created matrix will have an entry for each demandpoint/distance pair. The trick in the definition `d` is that there are two cases:

1. If a pair (i,j) is defined in `test1.csv` then the sum will match exactly one element in `distances`: the one that defines the distance between two points.
2. If a pair (i,j) is not defined in `test1.csv` then the sum will not match anything and the corresponding entry in the distance matrix will thus be 0.

Comment: I really appreciate your response. However, my problem is that the "text1" file is already created it has 100 nodes and 200 arcs ( it means there are just 200 distances). The thing that I should do is that find each of the indexes of demand points in a test 1 file and see if there is any distance between this point and any other point or not. Do you any solution for it?

Comment: I add the picture of the test1 file next to the weight file. the first column and second column are i and j and the third column is distance. because there are 200 distances some of the nodes have more than one arcs to other nodes. I should find the indexes of demand points and their distances with other nodes here and create a distance matrix. distance between demand points and other nodes. I hope I could explain properly.

Comment: Thanks for your update. And sorry that I repeated my question. It is because I did not see that you updated and I want more spaces to explain my question more than the comments that I use.

Comment: I just have one more question. I don't understand the way that you define float d. Why you use Sum? My objective function is: minimize sum (i in demandpoints, j in facilities) 
 d[i][j]*x[i][j]*w[i]; and when I use d in this objective, it gives me error.

Comment: You would have to show your full .mod file and the actual error you get to answer your question. In my answer I explained why I used sum: that is a trick to be able to handle the case in which a pair i,j exist *and* the case in which a pair i,j does not exist. In case the pair exists then the sum is over exactly one element and `d[i][j]` is the distance between i and j. If the pair does not exist then the sum is over zero elements and consequently `d[i][j] = 0`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The code is what you helped me through it and the objective function is what I wrote in the previous comment. The error that I get is 1. impossible to load model 2. Not an array type and it has a red underline under the  d[i][j]*x[i][j]*w[i]

Comment: Are you sure the error comes from `d`? Maybe `x` or `w` are not an array type? Does the error go away if you just remove `d` from your objective?

Comment: You were right the error comes from somewhere else. So, x defined as:              dvar boolean x[demandpoints][facilities];     AND w defined as: {int} w = {d.weight | d in demand }; Do you have any idea what is the problem?

Comment: I guess the problem is that `w` is a set, not an array. Hence you cannot index into it. To confirm this, remove `w` from your objective and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Hi @maahnoosh if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: yes, you were right. How can I define w as an array? because w is equal to the weight which is a set of the tuple. Also could you please introduce sources that I can learn coding in CPLEX?

Comment: @XavierNodet Sorry I'm not familiar with this website. I accepted it.

Comment: A good starting point for learning CPLEX are the product's documentation and tutorials here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/maps/globals/opl_KC_home.html.

I don't know how to write `w` as an array since I don't know what `i` and `j` are in your case and how the rest of the model looks. Since this is now independent of the original question (which was about reading data from CSV) I suggest that you start a new question with respect to the issue with `w` and also post your full model there. This make it much easier to help you.