# Search in a csv file and find elements in another csv file in cplex

Tags: csv, search, tuples, cplex

I have two CSV files. One of them (weight.csv) has two columns which are indexes and weights of the 20 nodes. The other one (test.csv) has three columns, the first column is i= 1...100 j=1...100 and this column is the distances between nodes. at the end, there are some more rows because some of the nodes have more than one arcs between nodes. For example node number 34 repeated two times in column one because it has two distance between node number 35 and 8. I want to know how can I write code to search in the test.csv file and find the indexes in the weight.csv file and show me all the existed distance for that 20 number of nodes.
Please help me if you know the answer.

Comment: Please refine your question to explain what you tried, and why it doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: could https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=8b4ebc90-5aef-4438-a561-124b094ec6c4&ps=25 help ?

Comment: Isn't that the exact same question I have answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56100539/read-csv-file-in-cplex/56117237
Note that I updated my answer for your data and even included the code you need to build the distance matrix. In any case, I think your issue is unrelated to CSV. We already provided code to read the CSV files into tuples. Once you have the data in the tuple sets you just have to massage it a little (see my answer in that other thread).

Comment: Thanks for your responses. You're right I did not see your explanations. I wanted to explain my problem more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read CSV file in Cplex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56100539/read-csv-file-in-cplex)